# How can I add Toast say "no internet connection " to webview?

Tags: android

I want to add Toast say "no internet connection " to this webview code , I tried more than once but failed , I open this webview by button in MainActivity , I was hoping to write a clean and complete webview code but I had few experiences in the android plez help , the code

```
public class ShowWeb extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
WebView webview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_web);

    String Url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

    WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web.loadUrl(Url);


    //Get webview
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    //startWebView("http://50.73.3.244/Mobile/");

    // Javascript inabled on webview
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Other webview options التكبير والتصغير
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //Other webview settings
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
}

//Show loader on url load
public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

    // if url contains string androidexample
    // Then show progress  Dialog
    if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("lol")
            ) {

        // in standard case YourActivity.this
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowWeb.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to solve this issue.

**Way 1:**

Checking internet connection first. If available then load the url, else show Toast with message "No Internet Available".

```
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) {
    web.loadUrl(Url);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

...

```
public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable (Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

}
```

**Way 2:**
Load your default page from assets using onReceivedError callback of `WebViewClient`.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
      // show no internet connection toast message here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check before calling web view .

```
           if (internet)
      {

 String Url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.loadUrl(Url);


//Get webview
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
//startWebView("http://50.73.3.244/Mobile/");

// Javascript inabled on webview
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// Other webview options التكبير والتصغير
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

//webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

//Other webview settings
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

  }else{
Toast.makeText(getActivity,"no internet",LARGETEXT).show();
  }
```